# how can i deploy scala on heroku

Tags: scala, heroku

i am following this [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-scala) to deploy scala into heroku.

but i got `H14 error in heroku - "no web processes running"`

i found in internet i must have dyno active `heroku ps:scale web=1`

but this service is not free. to be valid user, we must enter credit card on heroku.
that meant Heroku is not free anymore ?

so how can i deploy scala API on heroku for free ?

my Procfile : `web: target/universal/stage/bin/conspille2`

my sbt [image]

did i put Procfile in the right folder. it said on Root.
it is ambigue in root like i did or in root of app ?

[image]

Comment: What's the content of procfile? Also, don't post [code as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: And please [edit] the contents of your `Procfile` into your question. All relevant information should be included there, not in comments.

Comment: "i found in internet i must have dyno active `heroku ps:scale web=1` but this service is not free"—what does "free" have to do with anything? You'd use the same command (or a variant of it) to scale any type of dyno on Heroku. Are you still trying to use free dynos? They no longer exist as of about a week ago.